# System.Net.Http.HttpClient Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer.CreateClient()

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-testhost

For some reasons, I am unable to run any tests when using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` package. Here's the exception thrown:

```
System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer.CreateClient()'.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I had to put this in my project csproj.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Not sure that makes sense. Sounds like you have incompatible dependencies

Comment: @davidfowl I found the solution here: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/926